# springboot - basic ActiveDirectory auth then JWT token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Has anyone got a working example of this in a springboot app?

1. /auth controller where user provides ActiveDirectory credentials (either via basic auth or a POST json) and receives a JWT token if they provided valid AD credentials. No LDIF file should be involved, the Springboot app will verify the credentials against an ldaps://ActiveDirectoryhost:636 endpoint
2. /myapi controller which only works if valid JWT token from step1 (above) sent in 'Authorization Bearer' heading

I have not found any example blogs/guides with this setup but I believe this would be a common security setup unless I am mistaken?
No jpa/hibernate/persistence/mysql/postgres/H2db connections should be involved
All examples I found online either are just JWT, or just LDAP, or use LDIF or use some H2/postgres to store credentials.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/SNCF-SIV/spring-security-rest-jwt-ldap/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sncf/siv/poc/security/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134515/spring-5-ldap-authentication-and-jwt-token-as-response

Comment: Thanks, but 1st link is not SpringBoot and 2nd link is using LDIF :(

Comment: Have you find any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

JWT from https://github.com/merugu/springsecurity/tree/master/ldapauthenticationjwttoken

AD from https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-active-directory-authentication-5ea04969f220

Had to upgrade the github jwt repo to springboot 2.0.5 and add setSearchFilter {1} (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) to AD

This 2nd option also worked on Springboot 1.5:
[Spring security switch to Ldap authentication and database authorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658534/spring-security-switch-to-ldap-authentication-and-database-authorities) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34658755) on top of https://github.com/cnapagoda/spring-boot-basic-auth